# Detecting noise/artifacts in an image

Tags: php, linux, image, ocr

Is there a reliable way of detecting noise or artifacts in an image, consisting of text and images (page from a PDF file), while not harming the text or "real" pictures. Only removing the noise, specks, blotches, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, there is no *reliable, non-destructive* way -- this would mean to ask a computer program to "magically" know what's noise and what is not. However, there are methods that get close in practice.

One commonly applied method which is reasonably simple and often not very destructive is a small radius (3-5) [median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter). A median filter is good at finding scratches or "wrong pixel" noise.

Another noise reducing method would be a [bilateral filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter), which in layman terms is basically a blur that respects features.

Yet another method to detect and filter noise would be akin to the technique Pixar used in their "wavelet noise" algorithm:

- downsample the image (e.g. by one mip level, a.k.a. 1/2 in every direction)
- subtract the downsampled image from the original (implicitly upsampling again)
- what remains, the difference, is what couldn't be represented in the lower resolution image, thus noise

Answer (score 0):

There's no statistical way which would exactly remove noise, you can use Super Resolution GANs though, make a sythetic data and train your model for noisy to clean images.